# SQL Subtract Dates--Datetime functions invalidate query

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I'm having trouble with `datetime` functions and so far no tutorial/Q&A message board has provided a functioning answer:

My goal: to pull a list of orders where the most recent order note is 5 days prior to today's date. Order note datetime populates in the "create_date" column.

My dilemma: I want to find orders with a MAX(create_date) of NOW()-5 days. The only datetime function that has done anything is NOW() which works well enough, but I can't seem to find the function/syntax that will subtract 5 days from today's date and actually work.

Here is my functioning query (I know it may look messy to the more seasoned of you, but I'm relatively new and right now just want results):

```
SELECT cant.*
FROM  (
      SELECT notes.order_number, create_date, note_text, admin_username, 
      ships.status
      FROM ordernotes notes
      JOIN shipments ships
      ON notes.order_number=ships.order_number
      WHERE ships.status='cant_fulfill'
      AND create_date<NOW()
      ) cant    
WHERE admin_username IN ('name','name','name','name')
AND note_text LIKE '%LTK%'
LIMIT 30
```

This pulls the appropriate kind of results, but I need to filter those results to find the `MAX(create_date`) of 5 days prior to NOW(). I have considered trying to use the `MAX()` function somewhere, but if I try that, the query fails.

Below are some examples of simple queries I have tested and the result. I'm at a loss.

```
SELECT * FROM ordernotes LIMIT 10: WORKS. 
SELECT MAX(create_date)FROM ordernotes LIMIT 10: WORKS
SELECT MAX(create_date), order_number, sku FROM ordernotes LIMIT 10: --FAILS--
SELECT * FROM ordernotes WHERE MAX(create_date)<NOW() LIMTI 10:--FAILS--
SELECT * FROM ordernotes WHERE MAX(create_date)='2017-10-01':--FAILS--
```

Comment: Your queries don't look like SQL Server

Comment: Is this MySQL? Tag the dbms accurately.

Comment: It is mysql , please change the tag to mysql

Comment: Thank you for the input. My job only requires minimal use of this tool and this job has been my first exposure to it. As such, the training was minimal and vague. I wasn't even aware it was MySQL, though I suspected something like that might be the issue. I have changed the tag, as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ANSI SQL standard, which works in Oracle, PostgreSQL, and MySQL, to grab all records before 5 days ago, you do:

```
WHERE create_date < (NOW() - INTERVAL '5' DAY)
```

[MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) has an additional syntax:

```
WHERE create_date < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -5 DAY)
```

[MS SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql) does not recognise the standard interval, and has its own syntax:

```
WHERE create_date < DATEADD(DAY, -5, GETDATE())
```

Comment: You just saved my sanity.

Comment: I suspected this might be the issue but didn't have a knowledge base deep enough to discern the proper language. My training just referred to it as "SQL". Looks like PostgreSQL is probably the answer to my problems. Of the three options provided, only that one worked.

Comment: Actually there **is** a standard for adding or subtracting dates: `where create_date < current_date - interval '5' day` (and that works at least in Postgres and Oracle)

Comment: Woops, you're right. I forgot they're both of the PL/ variant (haven't used Oracle in 15 years).

Comment: That has nothing to do with "PL/ variant" - that syntax is defined by the **SQL standard** (an this question is about SQL, not PL/SQL or PL/pgSQL)

Comment: Oh hey, once again you're right. Never realised that was the ANSI standard. Thanks! (was this SQL-92 or later?)